# How to add incremental column type float in Ruby on Rails with Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

> I am adding a new column to table but I wanted to be its
>   auto_increment with float type. I am using postgresql, I don't know
>   how to do please suggest below is the migration

```
class AddPositionToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :items, :position, :float
  end
end
```

Comment: `:auto_increment` and `:float` are you sure about this?

Comment: Yes @AlejandroMontilla , Actually I need to save some float values to position column. (I have some logic behind to calculate its average and then sort position column values so that why I need float and Incremental)

Comment: I dont think that migration supports this. But you can implement your logic in other places (perhabs in your model). That make sense to your case?

Comment: I guess there is an option to execute postgresql statement but I am not sure about this.

Comment: You can edit your Post (or add a new one) explaining your situation. Something like this: "I need to calculate the salary average (from table Worker) when a new worker is inserted." And if you have your logic implemented, It would be really helpful if you add it.